# ajax function not working fine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a text field in which i am getting a string like that

say name / contact / address

and i get this value on button click function when i pass this value to php function via ajax. it returns nothing, i don't know what is wrong with my code.

here is the ajax function:

```
$("#load").click(function()
{
    //alert("this comes in this");
    var data1 = $("#country_id").val();
    $.ajax({
        alert("ajax start");
            url: 'ajax_submit.php',
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{getRespondents:"getRespondents", data:data1},
            success: function(e){
                    alert(e);
                    $("#rCategory").val(e.respondents[0]['category']);
                    $("#gender").val(e.respondents[0]['gender']);
                    $("#rAddress").val(e.respondents[0]['address']);
                    $("#rContact").val(e.respondents[0]['contact']);
                    alert("In this");
            }
      });
});
```

and in ajax_submit.php function is like that:

```
if($_POST["getRespondents"] == "getRespondents"){
      $regionID= $_POST["data"];
      $obj = new controller();
      $result = $obj->getRespondents($regionID);
      $json = array("respondents"=>$result);
      echo json_encode($json);
      exit();
 }
```

In class function is written as:

```
function getRespondents($a){
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server..
    $db = mysql_select_db("demon", $connection); // Selecting Database


    list($number1, $number2, $number3) = explode('/', $a);
    //$sql = "SELECT r.id, r.name, r.contact, r.address from respondent as r ORDER BY r.name";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM respondent as r WHERE r.name = '".$number1."' and r.contact = '".$number2."' and r.address = '".$number3."' "
    $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
    $row= array();
    $i=0;
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
        $row[$i]["id"]      = $rs ['id'];
        $row[$i]["name"]    = $rs ['name'];
        $row[$i]["contact"] = $rs ['contact'];
        $row[$i]["address"] = $rs ['address'];
        $row[$i]["category"] = $rs ['category'];
        $row[$i]["gender"] = $rs ['gender'];
        $i++;
    }
    return $row;
}
```

I want to populate those values in given select boxes when user selects something from autocomplete function.

what are possible soultions to this problem? thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console? Any errors?

Comment: The possible solution for your unnamed problem is to debug process step-by-step. Checking/debugging `data1`, Ajax result, PHP code.

Comment: i think the problem is here data:{getRespondents:"getRespondents", data:data1}, here you change the variable name data to some other name

Comment: e.respondents[i]['category'] here i is undefined

Comment: What do you mean by 'returns nothing'? Does it go to success function in the ajax setup?

Comment: @JayBlanchard when i first load the page it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("

Comment: You have to fix that error, then your code may work.

Comment: @satishrajak i changed them like a many times but all fail,

Comment: Additionally you have two `$sql` variables. `$rsd = mysql_query($sql);` will only execute the second one.

Comment: @JqueryKing i made it 0 index now. but still nothing is on page.

Comment: @JayBlanchard okay let me try

Comment: [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: i want print console.log(e) then told the result

Answer (score 1):

First of all why you use alert at the beginning of ajax? remove that alert because it might give you JavaScript error.